# a web view without a given height

Tags: dart, flutter

Can I set a `WebView` with inline URL inside my widget tree without giving the `WebView` a specific height and let it expand or shrink according to the size of the received content?

Now I have to give the webview a height or I will face the exception:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():

I/flutter ( 6783): RenderAndroidView object was given an infinite size during layout.

I/flutter ( 6783): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put

I/flutter ( 6783): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.

I/flutter ( 6783): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is:

I/flutter ( 6783):   RenderIndexedSemantics#dbf32 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

I/flutter ( 6783):   creator: IndexedSemantics ← 

NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ←

I/flutter ( 6783):   AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverList ← MediaQuery ← 

SliverPadding ← ShrinkWrappingViewport ←

I/flutter ( 6783):   IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#ae5f8] ← Semantics ← Listener ← 
_GestureSemantics ← ⋯

I/flutter ( 6783):   parentData: index=4; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)

I/flutter ( 6783):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)

I/flutter ( 6783):   semantic boundary

I/flutter ( 6783):   size: MISSING

I/flutter ( 6783):   index: 4
```